# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, type-conversion, typeerror

I having trouble passing a function as a parameter to another function. This is my code:

**ga.py:**

```py
def display_pageviews(hostname):
    pageviews_results = get_pageviews_query(service, hostname).execute()
    if pageviews_results.get('rows', []):
        pv = pageviews_results.get('rows')
        return pv[0]
    else:
        return None


def get_pageviews_query(service, hostname):  
    return service.data().ga().get(
        ids=VIEW_ID,
        start_date='7daysAgo',
        end_date='today',
        metrics='ga:pageviews',
        sort='-ga:pageviews',
        filters='ga:hostname==%s' % hostname,)
```

**models.py:**

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField('auth.User')
    views = models.IntegerField()
    visits = models.IntegerField()
    unique_visits = models.IntegerField()
```

**updatestats.py:**

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        users = User.objects.all()
        try:
            for user in users:
                hostname = '%s.%s' % (user.username, settings.NETWORK_DOMAIN)
                stats = Stats.objects.update_or_create(
                    user=user,
                    views=display_pageviews(hostname),
                    visits=display_visits(hostname),
                    unique_visits=display_unique_visits(hostname),)
        except FieldError:
            print ('There was a field error.')
```

When I run this: `python manage.py updatestats` I get the error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

I don't know what's causing this. I've tried converting it to a string, but I get the same error. Any ideas?

**Full traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 20, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/project_files/project/main/management/commands/updatestats.py", line 23, in handle
    unique_visits=display_unique_visits(hostname),)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 480, in update_or_create
    obj = self.get(**lookup)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 378, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 790, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 808, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1243, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1269, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1203, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1099, in build_lookup
    return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 57, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1860, in get_prep_lookup
    return super(IntegerField, self).get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 744, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/Dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1854, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

I used the shell to get the type of function output:

```py
type(display_pageviews('test.domain.com'))
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. Apart from anything else, it'll tell us exactly where the error is occurring.

Comment: you can't convert a list to a string as it says

Comment: Make sure `return pv[0]` isn't giving you a list.

Comment: I am seeing this same error, except there is no traceback, so I have no idea where it's happening.  I'm sure it's in a library.  Something must be catching it, but that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

What the error is telling, is that you can't convert an entire list into an integer. You could get an index from the list and convert that into an integer:

```
x = ["0", "1", "2"] 
y = int(x[0]) #accessing the zeroth element
```

If you're trying to convert a whole list into an integer, you are going to have to convert the list into a string first:

```
x = ["0", "1", "2"]
y = ''.join(x) # converting list into string
z = int(y)
```

If your list elements are not strings, you'll have to convert them to strings before using `str.join`:

```
x = [0, 1, 2]
y = ''.join(map(str, x))
z = int(y)
```

Also, as stated above, make sure that you're not returning a nested list.

Comment: But why isn't his `try except` catching this?

Comment: @geoidesic because except has only been instructed to catch `FieldError`. `TypeError` is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object, or a number, not 'NoneType'

According to the error, you can't convert strings type data into integers, So if a column contains null values as NaN then the type of NaN is float, so you can convert that into float.

check type of NaN -> type(np.NaN) ==> float

Answer (score 1):

```
integer_list = [int(item) for line in list for item in line]
```

In this way you can convert string to integer in a list

Answer (score 0):

If you got this error, it means that your code got an unexpected input which probably means that there should be handled as an error or if it's a valid input, add/change code to account for it. One way is to iterate over this list and handle each element one-by-one. For example,

```py
result = ['1', '2', '3']   # e.g. got this from some API
int(result)                # <--- TypeError
[int(x) for x in result]   # <--- no error
```

In the same vein, for example in the OP, since OP is using Google Analytics, the output of `get_pageviews_query` would look like:

```py
results = {
    'columnHeaders': [{'name': 'ga:date'}, {'name': 'ga:pageviews'}], 
    'rows': [['20240205', 33], ['20240206', 20], ['20240207', 12]]
}
```

which is a nested list and contains page views of different days; so instead of getting only the first value in the list, it's probably desirable to iterate through this list and use all pageviews.

So a solution for OP (albeit 7 years too late) would be to change `updatestats.py` to account for this (valid) list input.

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        users = User.objects.all()
        try:
            for user in users:
                hostname = '%s.%s' % (user.username, settings.NETWORK_DOMAIN)
                for _, pv in display_pageviews(hostname):        # <--- iterate over the list
                    stats = Stats.objects.update_or_create(
                        user=user,
                        views=pv,                                # <--- add each pageview value
                        visits=display_visits(hostname),
                        unique_visits=display_unique_visits(hostname),)
        except FieldError:
            print ('There was a field error.')
```