# Weird TypeError when calling simple matplotlib function

Tags: python, error-handling

I have been trying to execute some matplotlib.pyplot code and kept getting this random error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'KeyboardModifier'

When I tried to simply put the tutorial code in to see if it was a problem with my code, I got the same error.

I literally tried to run:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

and still got the same error?

for full error code things, this is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\stefa\OneDrive - Catholic Education Western Australia\Desktop\Coding\python\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2730, in plot
    return gca().plot(
           ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2227, in gca
    return gcf().gca()
           ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 832, in gcf
    return figure()
           ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 454, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 773, in figure
    manager = new_figure_manager(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 348, in new_figure_manager
    _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread()
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 338, in _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread
    if (_get_required_interactive_framework(_get_backend_mod()) and
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 207, in _get_backend_mod
    switch_backend(dict.__getitem__(rcParams, "backend"))
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 252, in switch_backend
    switch_backend(candidate)
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 265, in switch_backend
    backend_mod = importlib.import_module(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qtagg.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .backend_qt import QtCore, QtGui, _BackendQT, FigureCanvasQT
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 72, in <module>
    _MODIFIER_KEYS = [
                     ^
  File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 73, in <listcomp>
    (_to_int(getattr(_enum("QtCore.Qt.KeyboardModifier"), mod)),
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'KeyboardModifier'
```

Any extra help would be much appreciated!

Comment: it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836795/typeerror-int-argument-must-be-a-string-a-bytes-like-object-or-a-number-not

Comment: or restart your server

Comment: Your code is working perfectly in other systems...Just uninstall matplotlib & install again or else just restart laptop